# Django order_by according to inline's updated time

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm trying to list my objects according to it's inline objects' updated time.
Here is my models.py:

```
class Baslik(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)


    def get_absolute_url(self, ):
        return reverse('baslik', args=[self.slug])


class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    baslik = models.ForeignKey(Baslik, null=True, blank=True)
    icerik = models.TextField(max_length=50000)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.icerik)
```

As you see I connected the Entry model with Baslik model via ForeignKey.
I use this part of views.py to list objects according to time they have created:

```
def hepsi(request):
    basliklar = Baslik.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-updated')

    return render_to_response("base.html", 
                               locals(), 
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can I reach my aim. Any opinions would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of hepsi function worked.

```
def hepsi(request):

    basliklar = Baslik.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-updated')



    gunlist = []

    for i in basliklar:

        entryler = i.entry_set.all()
        ent1 = entryler.latest('id')
        ent2 = ent1.updated
        ent3 = str(ent2).split(" ")
        zaman1 = date.today()
        zaman2 = str(zaman1).split(" ")
        zamangun = zaman2[0]
        entgun = ent3[0]

        if entgun == zamangun:
            gunlist.append(i)


    cta = {'basliklar': basliklar, 'entryler': entryler, 'ent1': ent1, 'ent2': ent2, 'entgun': entgun, 'zamangun': zamangun, 'gunlist': gunlist}

    return render(request, "base.html", cta)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the entries by the baslik's updated time, the syntax would be:

order_by("-baslik__updated")

Notice the double underscores.